# web server to application server communication

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I Need to pass request from web server to application server.

web server and application server lies in a separate box.

so what is the best technology to use in this scenario ?

Web Server : I have html page, i need to fill it and submit.

Application server : I need  to receive that submitted request with all the form values and need to perform some action.

in application layer , i am planning to do mapping to spring controller , is it fine ?

please explain the best possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Personal experience is use service-oriented-architecture for communications between servers.

So if u have App Server that wants to communicate with Web Server then create services (e.g. WSDL) that will manage that communication.

This will enable data management, consistency, security and potentially transformation (if you need it).

The biggest benefit we have seen is the ability to remove the server and replace it without any other changes to code and still have it work off the bat.

Hope that helps